# Where has getCentralMoment gone in Pythons new openCV API?

Tags: python, opencv

I am using some tutorials on object tracking to create an easy gesture detection, but I am having trouble finding the functions `GetSpatialMoment` and `GetCentralMoment` or equivalent in the new `cv2` API.

The tutorial codes always look [like this](http://www.davidhampgonsalves.com/2011/05/OpenCV-Python-Color-Based-Object-Tracking), but they are always in old cv1:

```
moments = cv.Moments(thresholded_img, 0) 
area = cv.GetCentralMoment(moments, 0, 0) 

#there can be noise in the video so ignore objects with small areas 
if(area > 100000): 
    #determine the x and y coordinates of the center of the object 
    #we are tracking by dividing the 1, 0 and 0, 1 moments by the area 
    x = cv.GetSpatialMoment(moments, 1, 0)/area 
    y = cv.GetSpatialMoment(moments, 0, 1)/area
```

What new `cv2` functions to I have to use for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new Python interface returns all moments directly. You can access the required moments via the indices like `m00`, `m01` or `m10`. So the above code in `cv2` would be:

```
moments = cv2.moments(thresholded_img) 
area = moments['m00'] 

#there can be noise in the video so ignore objects with small areas 
if(area > 100000): 
    #determine the x and y coordinates of the center of the object 
    #we are tracking by dividing the 1, 0 and 0, 1 moments by the area 
    x = moments['m10'] / area
    y = moments['m01'] / area
```